# Add child node to KendoTreeView wirh remote datasource

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-treeview

I have a KendoTreeView which is bound to a  `HierarchicalDataSource` and filled from a parent/child Table from DB. I have an ADD button to add child node to selected node. 
The below is my code:

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Folder_Read", "Home")",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: 'GET'
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "fol_ID",
                    hasChildren: "fol_HasChildren"
                }
            }
        });

        var treeview = $("#treeview-folder").kendoTreeView({               
            template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: false
            },
            dataSource: dataSource,
            dataTextField: "fol_Title",              
            select: select_tree,              
        });
        $("#appendNodeToSelected").click(function (event) {
            var selectedNode = treeview.data("kendoTreeView").select();
            if (selectedNode.length == 0) {
                selectedNode = null;
            }
            var nodeText = prompt("Please enter desired Node name", "Default");
            if (nodeText == null) {
                return;
            }

            var obj= treeview.append(
               { fol_ID: 0, fol_Title: nodeText }
               , selectedNode              
               );           
        });
```

but this is not worked as well. 
The child folder isn't add neither visually or call controller.
How can I define an action and controller for it to add child node to DB ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my mistake finally. I had forgotten to write `treeview.data("kendoTreeView").append` instead of `treeview.append` .The child folder now is added visually.